# Power BI Embedded RLS , split username() and seach not working

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OK7rX.png)

In this username has value is '1,2,3'. How I can split and then check

requirement is split the string then convert each value into number then compare

I tried splitting but not able to find how to do in DAX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cheeky way:

```
CONTAINSSTRING("," & UserName() & ",", "," & [ContactId] & ",")
```

Another way closer to SPLIT is using [`PATHCONTAINS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/pathcontains-function-dax) but the delimiter needs to be a `|` (pipe).

```
PATHCONTAINS(
  SUBSTITUTE(UserName(), ",", "|"),
  [ContactId]
)
```